# How can I fix CLion problem with filesystem inlcude?

Tags: c++, c++17, clion

I use a CLion as my IDE. I create project with C++17 standard.
I have a code fragment below:

```
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::vector<std::string> getFilesArray() {

    auto dir = ".";
    std::vector<std::string> filesList;
    for (auto item : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir))
    {
        if (!fs::is_regular_file(item.path()) || item.path().extension() != ".cpp" && item.path().extension() != ".h" && item.path().extension() != ".hpp")
            continue;
        filesList.push_back(item.path().string());
    }

    return filesList;
}
```

When I try to compile project I have a lot of errors like:

```
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h: In member function 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path& std::filesystem::__cxx11::path::operator/=(const std::filesystem::__cxx11::path&)':
C:/PROGRA~2/MINGW-~1/I686-8~1.0-P/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/include/c++/bits/fs_path.h:237:47: error: no match for 'operator!=' (operand types are 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path' and 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::path')
    || (__p.has_root_name() && __p.root_name() != root_name()))
```

My Cmake file is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(FinalParser)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -lc++fs")


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(FinalParser main.cpp Parse/Parser.cpp Parse/Parser.cpp Parse/Parser.h files.h Graph/Parser.cpp Graph/Parser.h)
target_link_libraries(FinalParser stdc++fs)


SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "C:/Users/user/Desktop/boost_1_71_0")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "C:/Users/user/Desktop/boost_1_71_0/libs")

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)
IF (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
ENDIF()
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The error above has nothing to do with the posted code snippet. If you compile just this function, what happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile error when std::filesystem header file is added to my program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890493/compile-error-when-stdfilesystem-header-file-is-added-to-my-program) or [MinGW-w64 8.1.0 rev 0 doesn't compile when including <filesystem>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50546025/mingw-w64-8-1-0-rev-0-doesnt-compile-when-including-filesystem)

Comment: Unfortunatley no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I am going to give you the full proof solution for this similar error which also comes when someone tries to use the STL header file which is #include<bits/stdc++.h>

So, this error is occurring because you are currently using the GCC version 8.2.0 which is the default on the MinGW website. To solve this problem you need to update to GCC 10.2.0

Following are the steps you need to follow:-

1. Download and install the Msys2 from https://www.msys2.org/
2. Run or launch this and type pacman -Syu and hit enter then it will ask you to continue by typing Y/N just type enter without pressing Y/n.
3. Close this and again launch msys2 and again type the same command until it shows nothing to do with or nothing to update.
4. For doing the same I am also sharing a link of the youtube video.
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXF4A5UeSeM&

5. For checking that you have successfully installed GCC 10.2.0 just open cmd and type GCC --version and hit enter if it is showing 10.2.0 hurray u did it, wait this is not the end.
6. Now uninstall Clion or any IDE which you are using.
7. Before reinstalling it you need to delete some of the remaining Jetbrains dump files which are showing in your program files folder (name Jetbrains) Delete that folder and  Reinstall it.
8. Now select Msys2/MingW-64, not the previous one which you have in your system already (normal MinGW) while installing it.
9. Now You can go to your add or remove program section and can delete that waste normal MinGW-64, not the msys2 (don't delete msys2) only delete ming64 the previous one.
10. Now you can enjoy running that sexy stl library without having any error.

Still, if you have any problem doing these steps just ask me in a comment.